# Ubuntu Core/snap as a base for a virtualization host?

Tags: lvm, kvm-virtualization, ubuntu-core, snap

Ubuntu core / snap has some features I'd like to use as the base for a kvm virtualization host. (There's lot of web pages dealing with running ubuntu core in kvm, but I'd like to do it the other way round, run kvm in a core system).

I currently miss snaps like kvm, lvm (for raid disks) or even zfs.

Is there any chance to have this supported or would I have to craft these as snaps by myself?

Are there any plans to support this?

Answer (score 2):

Ubuntu Core would make a great minimalist, secure hypervisor, yes. I think you will want to look at creating some specific snap interfaces in snapd to enable access to the hypervisor capabilities of the system, but once you have that you'll be able to make snaps that launch VMs and attach them to networks easily enough.